# Setting colors of UITableViewCell and UITableView background

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I was trying to use a background image for my TableView so I don't get the leftover tableview cells when there isn't enough data to populate the whole table on screen, so I tried to follow this URL, but much simpler:  http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

I do this in the viewcontroller that has an outlet to my UITableView:

```
    UIImage *backgroundTableImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"form_background.png"]; // basically a gray->white gradient
    UIImageView *tableBackgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundTableImage];
    tableBackgroundImageView.frame = self.TableView.bounds;
    self.TableView.backgroundView = tableBackgroundImageView;
    [tableBackgroundImageView release];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Then I have a custom subclass of UITableViewCell that I create in IB.  In IB, it's background is set to White-default.  My cells are all transparent, and I only see my background.  How do I get my cells to stay white.

Comment: This line `tableBackgroundImageView.frame = self.TableView.bounds` does not seem right. Are you sure this is doing what you want?

Answer (score 0):

At first take a view in your .h file UIView *newView; declare its property and synhesize it at your .m file

Now in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if(cell==nil){

        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]];

................
.........
newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:newView];
................
...............
}
if(indexPath.row == 0){

newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

}
if(indexPath.row == 1){

newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
if(indexPath.row == 2){

newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

}
```

If any further question please knock me.